# Where In + Rand() + Limit

Tags: mysql, sql, random, limit

I have a db "link" like this:

```
id(primary) | name_id | type | url
```

I am trying to find for 5 unique name_id a random URL. I thought to do this for only one:

```
SELECT url
FROM link
WHERE name_id=1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

It works. So, I thought for five, to do like this:

```
SELECT url
FROM link
WHERE name_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

But, it's not working because it finds 2 results for name_id=1 and 3 results for name_id=2, for example (in db I can have 10+ rows for one name_id).

I want to return one random url for each name_id in 1 request SQL. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the five, then you can use `union all`:

```
(SELECT url FROM link WHERE name_id = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT url FROM link WHERE name_id = 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT url FROM link WHERE name_id = 3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT url FROM link WHERE name_id = 4 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT url FROM link WHERE name_id = 5 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
);
```

There are other methods of getting "random" rows that are faster, if performance is an issue.

However, if you only have 10 or so URLs for a given name, then the above should be okay . . . especially with an index on `link(name_id, url)`.